# Merge hashes with arrays with Hash::Merge

Tags: perl

I am trying to merge two hashes which contains one or more arrays using [`Hash::Merge`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Merge). For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use Data::Dump qw(dump);
use Hash::Merge qw(merge);

my $h1 = { a => [ { aa => 1 }, 3 ] };
my $h2 = { a => [ { bb => 2 } ] };

my $hLeft  = merge( $h1, $h2 );
my $hRight = merge( $h2, $h1 );

say "  hLeft: " . dump($hLeft);
say " hRight: " . dump($hRight);

my $hDesired = { a => [ { aa => 1, bb => 2 }, 3 ] };
say "Desired: " . dump($hDesired);
```

This gives output:

```
  hLeft: { a => [{ aa => 1 }, 3, { bb => 2 }] }
 hRight: { a => [{ bb => 2 }, { aa => 1 }, 3] }
Desired: { a => [{ aa => 1, bb => 2 }, 3] }
```

How can I get the correct output using `Hash::Merge` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior for merging arrays is to append them:

```
sub { [ @{$_[0]}, @{$_[1]} ] },
```

To get different behavior, one must use [`Hash::Merge::specify_behavior`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Merge).

The following solution is LEFT_PRECEDENT, and merges arrays element to element:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use Data::Dump qw(dump);
use Hash::Merge qw(merge);

Hash::Merge::specify_behavior(
    {   'SCALAR' => {
            'SCALAR' => sub { $_[0] },
            'ARRAY'  => sub { $_[0] },
            'HASH'   => sub { $_[0] },
        },
        'ARRAY' => {
            'SCALAR' => sub { [ @{ $_[0] }, $_[1] ] },
            'ARRAY'  => sub {
                my ( $left, $right ) = @_;

                my @merged = @$left;
                my @to_add = @$right;

                for (@merged) {
                    last if !@to_add;
                    $_ = Hash::Merge::merge( $_, shift @to_add );
                }

                return [ @merged, @to_add ];
            },
            'HASH'  => sub { [ @{ $_[0] }, values %{ $_[1] } ] },
        },
        'HASH' => {
            'SCALAR' => sub { $_[0] },
            'ARRAY'  => sub { $_[0] },
            'HASH'   => sub { Hash::Merge::_merge_hashes( $_[0], $_[1] ) },
        },
    },
    'My Behavior',
);

my $h1 = { a => [ { aa => 1 }, 3 ] };
my $h2 = { a => [ { bb => 2 } ] };

my $merged = merge( $h1, $h2 );
say "Merged: " . dump($merged);
```

Outputs:

```
Merged: { a => [{ aa => 1, bb => 2 }, 3] }
```

Comment: Thanks Miller! I see from your code that I should have used `merge` instead of `_merge_hashes`. I like your simplified version much more than mine :)

Comment: Correct, Arguments for _merge_hashes must be hash references.  You were checking that they were refs, but an error would've been thrown if an arrayref snuck into your arrays.  Also, using merge simplified the logic since it enabled the module to handle the data type handling.  NP for help, and thanks for the inspiration for picking up a new tool.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using [**`Hash::Merge::specify_behavior`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Hash::Merge#specify_behavior) :

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dump 'dump';
use Hash::Merge;
use feature 'say';

Hash::Merge::specify_behavior
  ( {
     'SCALAR' => {
                 'SCALAR' => sub { $_[1] },
                 'ARRAY'  => sub { [ $_[0], @{$_[1]} ] },
                 'HASH'   => sub { $_[1] },
                },
     'ARRAY' => {
                'SCALAR' => sub { $_[1] },
                'ARRAY'  => \&mergeArrays,
                'HASH'   => sub { $_[1] }, 
               },
     'HASH' => {
               'SCALAR' => sub { $_[1] },
               'ARRAY'  => sub { [ values %{$_[0]}, @{$_[1]} ] },
               'HASH'   => sub { Hash::Merge::_merge_hashes( $_[0], $_[1] ) }, 
              },
    }, 
    'My Behavior', 
  );

my $h1={a=>[{aa=>1},3]};
my $h2={a=>[{bb=>2}]};

my $hMerge=Hash::Merge::merge($h1,$h2);
say "hMerge: ".dump($hMerge);

sub mergeArrays{
    my ($a,$b)=@_;

    my ($na,$nb)=($#$a,$#$b);
    my @c;
    if ($na>$nb) {
        @c=@$a[($nb+1)..$na];
        return mergeArrays2($a,$b,\@c,$nb);
    } else {
        @c=@$b[($na+1)..$nb];
        return mergeArrays2($a,$b,\@c,$na);
    }
}

sub mergeArrays2{
    my ($a,$b,$c,$n)=@_;

    my $r=[];
    for my $i (0..$n) {
        if (ref($a->[$i]) && ref($b->[$i])) {
            push(@$r,Hash::Merge::_merge_hashes($a->[$i],$b->[$i]));
        } else {
            push(@$r,$a->[$i]);
        }
    }
    push(@$r,@$c);
    return $r;
}
```

Output:

```
hMerge: { a => [{ aa => 1, bb => 2 }, 3] }
```

Comment: It appears that you copy and pasted your solution from the docs for `Hash::Merge`.  It's important to note that the example they provided was RIGHT_PRECEDENT.  However, the specialized array merge that you coded is LEFT_PRECEDENT.  I therefore coded my own solution that is LEFT_PRECEDENT and also uses much simpler logic for the merge.