# Merge Perl Hashrefs and unique

Tags: arrays, perl, merge, unique, hashref

I havve got two perl hashes with the following contenct:

First:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'name1' => [
                   'adam',
                   'bob'
                 ],
      'name2' => [
                  'Miller',
                  'Schumacher'
                ]
    };
```

Second:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'name1' => [
                   'tina',
                   'jason',
                   'jeff'
                 ],
      'name2' => [
                  'Miller',
                  'Schumacher',
                  'Schmidt'
                ]
    };
```

How can I merge them both to get the following structure and to get unique items in name2 ?

```
$VAR1 = {
      'name1' => [
                   'tina',
                   'jason',
                   'jeff',
                   'adam',
                   'bob',
                 ],
      'name2' => [
                  'Miller',
                  'Schumacher',
                  'Schmidt'
                ]
    };
```

Comment: As a suggestion - you will generally get much better answers and responses if you show what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to loop over `name1, name2` keys and filter duplicates out of  `$VAR2->{$k}` and `$VAR1->{$k}` arrays,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $VAR1 = {
      'name1' => [ 'adam', 'bob' ],
      'name2' => [ 'Miller', 'Schumacher' ]
};
my $VAR2 = {
      'name1' => [ 'tina', 'jason', 'jeff' ],
      'name2' => [ 'Miller', 'Schumacher', 'Schmidt' ]
};

my %result;
for my $k (keys %$VAR1) {
  my %seen;
  $result{$k} = [
    grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @{ $VAR2->{$k} }, @{ $VAR1->{$k} }
  ];
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%result;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = {
      'name2' => [
                   'Miller',
                   'Schumacher',
                   'Schmidt'
                 ],
      'name1' => [
                   'tina',
                   'jason',
                   'jeff',
                   'adam',
                   'bob'
                 ]
    };
```

Comment: Thank you - whats the correct way to parse these now trough a foreach loop?

Answer (score 2):

[Hash::Merge](http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/Hash-Merge-0.200/lib/Hash/Merge.pm) module's right precedent behavior is customized to unify elements when merging arrays.

```
use strict;
use Hash::Merge qw/merge :custom/;
use List::MoreUtils qw/uniq/;
use Data::Dumper;

my $href1 = { name1 => [ qw/adam bob/ ],
              name2 => [ qw/Miller Schumacher/ ] };

my $href2 = { name1 => [ qw/tina jason jeff/ ],
              name2 => [ qw/Miller Schumacher Schmidt/ ] };

Hash::Merge::specify_behavior(  {
                        SCALAR => {
                                SCALAR => sub { $_[1] },
                                ARRAY  => sub { [ $_[0], @{$_[1]} ] },
                                HASH   => sub { $_[1] },
                        },
                        ARRAY => {
                                SCALAR => sub { $_[1] },
                                # This returns unique elements from two arrays passed
                                ARRAY  => sub { [ uniq( @{$_[0]}, @{$_[1]}) ] },
                                HASH   => sub { $_[1] }, 
                        },
                        HASH => {
                                SCALAR => sub { $_[1] },
                                ARRAY  => sub { [ values %{$_[0]}, @{$_[1]} ] },
                                HASH   => sub { Hash::Merge::_merge_hashes( $_[0], $_[1] ) }, 
                        },
                }, 
                'Right precedent + Uniq array', 
        );

my $href3 = merge($href1, $href2);

print Dumper $href3;
```

Produces the output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'name2' => [
                       'Miller',
                       'Schumacher',
                       'Schmidt'
                     ],
          'name1' => [
                       'adam',
                       'bob',
                       'tina',
                       'jason',
                       'jeff'
                     ]
        };
```

Comment: See also [Merge hashes with arrays with Hash::Merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547424/merge-hashes-with-arrays-with-hashmerge)

Answer (score 1):

If your need is very specific - merging two hashes with keys `name1` and `name2`, then the following should do the trick:

```
my $first = {
        name1 => [ qw(adam bob) ],
        name2 => [ qw(Miller Schumacher) ],
    };
my $second = {
        name1 => [ qw(tina jason jeff) ],
        name2 => [ qw(Miller Schumacher Schmidt) ],
    };

my $merged = {
        name1 => [ values %{$first->{name1}}, values %{$second->{name1}} ],
        name2 => [ values %{$first->{name2}}, values %{$second->{name2}} ],
    };
```

If the keys aren't fixed and known in advance, Сухой27's answer will work, at least if the structure is only two levels deep.
If it can go deeper, you'll need a recursive solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general solution that can take any number of hashes, and copes with a missing key in any of the hashes

It iterates over a list of all the hash keys to be combined, and joins the array values of each of those keys across all of the hashes using `map`

I have used `Data::Dump` only to display the resulting hash data

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw/ uniq /;
use Data::Dump;

my %ha = (
    name1 => [ "adam",   "bob" ],
    name2 => [ "Miller", "Schumacher" ],
);

my %hb = (
    name1 => [ "tina",   "jason",      "jeff" ],
    name2 => [ "Miller", "Schumacher", "Schmidt" ],
);

my @hashes = \( %ha, %hb );

my %new;

for my $k ( uniq map keys %$_, @hashes ) {
    $new{$k} = [
        uniq map @{ $_->{$k} // [] }, @hashes
    ];
}

dd \%new;
```

#### output

```
{
  name1 => ["adam", "bob", "tina", "jason", "jeff"],
  name2 => ["Miller", "Schumacher", "Schmidt"],
}
```

If for any reason you would prefer not to install the non-core library module [`List::MoreUtils`](http://metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils) then you can use this version of the `uniq` function

```
sub uniq {
  my %seen;
  grep { not $seen{$_}++ } @_;
}
```