# YAML merging with custom methods

Tags: perl, data-structures

I am trying to merge two yml's :-

```
use Hash::Merge qw( merge );
use YAML;
$file1 = a.yml
$file2 = b.yml
my $load1=&YAML::LoadFile($file1);
my $load2=&YAML::LoadFile($file2);
my $merge_data = merge($load1, $load2);
my $out_yml = Dump $final_soc_cfg_request;
```

Am i missing anything here in custom merge mechanism ?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67616264/4653379), to your question about `Hash::Merge` of a couple of months ago, applies here as well.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I don't really understand what you mean -- to adjust the `merge` behavior?  That can be done by coding exactly the desired behavior using its `add_behavior_spec` feature.  See the answer at the link in my comment above -- at its end there are links to how to use that feature. Another way, again, is to just `merge` and then post-process the result.

Comment: OK, I think I understand, thank you for explaining.  I have two questions.  (1) What do you mean to "_remove duplicates_" -- what duplicates?  (Do you mean that if there are multiple `source: etc` (for example) then to keep only one?  (2) Is it only two hashes?  Will it ever be more than two to merge, in your real program?

Comment: Alright, thank you.  It's late here now I'll post tomorrow.  (Btw, I think that your expected output, in the edit of the question, shouldn't have the second `-name...` section, right?)

Comment: @RAMA In your expected output there is an item with `name: tool_gen.config` but in the input files there is no such item. Both the input files have  `name: tool_log.config`, but not `tool_gen.config`. Please clarify.

Comment: @RAMA Thanks for the update. Now there is a `name: test_log.config` in the input file `a.yml` but no `name: test_log.config` in the expected output. Was that a typo?

Comment: @RAMA  I changed that `test_log.config` into `tool_log.config` as it by all means appeared to be a typo.  Please review and adjust if that is wrong (and then explain please!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using [Hash::Merge::add_behavior_spec](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Merge#add_behavior_spec(-%3Chashref%3E,-%5B%3Cname%3E%5D-)), for the data shown in the question.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';    
use Data::Dump qw(dd pp);
    
use Storable qw(dclone);
use YAML qw(LoadFile);
use Hash::Merge qw(merge);

die "Usage: $0 file1 file2\n" if @ARGV != 2;
my ($fname1, $fname2) = @ARGV;

my $yml1 = LoadFile($fname1);
my $yml2 = LoadFile($fname2);

# Naive merge doesn't do all that's wanted
#my $r = merge($yml1, $yml2); dd $r;

Hash::Merge::add_behavior_spec( {
    'SCALAR' => {
        'SCALAR' => sub { $_[0] },
        'ARRAY'  => sub { $_[0] },
        'HASH'   => sub { $_[0] },
    },
    'ARRAY' => {
        'SCALAR' => sub { [ @{ $_[0] }, $_[1] ] },
        'ARRAY'  => sub {
            # For each pair of hashrefs check whether three (of four) keys
            # have the same values; if so, merge them. If not then add them.
            my @res;
            # Scan: Which elements in each array to merge, and which with which
            my (%m1, %m2, %merge);
            my @a1 = @{$_[0]};
            my @a2 = @{$_[1]};
            I1: foreach my $i1 (0..$#a1) {
                I2: foreach my $i2 (0..$#a2) {
                    next if exists $m1{$i1} or exists $m2{$i2};
                    if (ref $a1[$i1] eq 'HASH' and ref $a2[$i2] eq 'HASH') {
                        for (qw(name project source)) {
                            next I2 if $a1[$i1]->{$_} ne $a2[$i2]->{$_};
                        }
                    }
                    # Three key-pairs are same so fourth ones need be merged
                    $m1{$i1} = $m2{$i2} = 1;
                    $merge{$i1} = $i2;
                }
            }

            # Now assemble/merge components as marked above
            my (%added_1, %added_2);       # more bookkeeping needed :(
            A1: foreach my $i1 (0..$#a1) {
                A2: foreach my $i2 (0..$#a2) {
                    next A2 if (exists $m1{$i1} and exists $m2{$i2})
                            or exists $added_2{$i2};
                    push @res, dclone $a2[$i2];
                    $added_2{$i2} = 1;
                }
                next A1 if exists $m1{$i1} or exists $added_1{$i1};   
                push @res, dclone $a1[$i1];
                $added_1{$i1} = 1;
            }

            foreach my $i (keys %merge) {
                push @res, 
                    Hash::Merge::_merge_hashes($a1[$i], $a2[$merge{$i}]);
            }
            \@res;
        },
        'HASH'  => sub { [ @{ $_[0] }, values %{ $_[1] } ] },
    },
    'HASH' => {
        'SCALAR' => sub { $_[0] },
        'ARRAY'  => sub { $_[0] },
        'HASH'   => sub { Hash::Merge::_merge_hashes( $_[0], $_[1] ) },
    },
}, 'Merge Arrayrefs Recursively As Well',);


my $res = merge($yml1, $yml2);

dd $res;
```

Each of the data structures to merge is an arrayref containing hashrefs.  When they are merged by the module the hashrefs are merely lumped together into one arrayref, while it is conceivable that some hashrefs in that arrayref can be merged further.<sup>†</sup>

This is remedied in the `ARRAY`-to-`ARRAY` rule above, where pairs of hashrefs are checked for whether they should be merged, and are labeled if so.  The criterion for merging is as follows.

Each hahref has three keys with string values, and another with an arrayref value.  If those three key-value pairs are the same then the hashrefs should be made into one with the three key-value pairs, while their arrayrefs for the fourth key should be merged into one, the value for that key.

Then in the second pass those that were marked for merging are subjected to the `_merge_hashes` routine while others are added to the resulting array.

This prints

```
{
  tool_pointer => [
    {
      name    => "tool_gen.config",
      project => "TOT",
      source  => "etc",
      tools   => [{ name => "vipcat" }, { name => "log" }],
    },
    {
      name    => "tool_log.config",
      project => "TOT",
      source  => "etc",
      tools   => [
                   { name => "xc" },
                   { name => "test" },
                   { name => "vr" },
                   { name => "arbgen2" },
                 ],
    },
  ],
}
```

I use [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) to display complex data structures, for its default simplicity and conciseness. (My choice; there are others of course, with [Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data::Dumper) being in the core, so installed already.)

This is merely a demo, as I've simplified things around, also using a fixed list of hardcoded key names, to get it working for the shown dataset.  Please fill in the details for your  real data.

Note that this has to be coded anew for each separate dataset and so must be reviewed, and perhaps adjusted or significantly changed, for any change in input data.

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32922686/4653379)
and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26557081/4653379) for a couple of other examples.

---

<sup>†</sup> No blame on the module though.  Array elements cannot be analyzed for whether, or how, to merge them as there cannot be general criteria for that. So then they are simply added to a resulting array, and for any more specific wants there is the `add_behavior_spec`.

Comment: @RAMA Hm, I never thought about that -- the docs imply that it only does two, "_.merges two ... hashes_", so I guess it can't be directly used for more.  But you can pair them up -- merge the first two, then merge the others one by one, always with the result of the previous merge

Comment: @RAMA "_how to merge more than 2._" -- One by one, always with the output of the previous merger.  For example, with `merge` as prepared in this answer:  (1) load all YAML files (like above, using `LoadFile`), say into `@yml`.  (2) Then merge first two: `my $res = merge(splice @yml, 0, 2);` (see [splice](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice)). (3) Merge the rest one by one, `while(my $yml = shift @yml) { $res = merge($res, $yml) };` In the end `$res` should be a merge of all of them -- if it works (does order or merging matter)?

Comment: @RAMA  This question is specifically about merging two files, and that is what I answered.  But I can add to the answer a section on how to merge more than two files (my previous comment, just written out more nicely), since that is related.  Let me know whether that'll be helpful.

Comment: your comments are sufficient @zdim. Thanks! I have another same requirement to deal with merging. Posted the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69257224/unable-to-merge-files-in-required-format    . Can you please check what is missing there?

Comment: could you please help!

Comment: @RAMA I'll be happy to look into it once I can (spare some extra time) -- that's not quick, it''s a long example and that takes time (I don't have a magic wand :).  Also, at first I wasn't sure why that problem isn't "covered" (helped substantially) by what's done here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can merge the hashes manually:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use experimental qw(signatures);
use List::Util qw(uniq);
use YAML;
{
    my $file1 = 'a.yml';
    my $file2 = 'b.yml';
    my $load1= YAML::LoadFile($file1);
    my $load2= YAML::LoadFile($file2);
    my $merge_data = merge($load1, $load2);
}

sub merge($hash1, $hash2) {
    my @hashes = ($hash1, $hash2);
    my %save;
    for my $hash (@hashes) {
        my $array = get_hash_value($hash,"tool_pointer", "ARRAY");
        for my $sub_hash (@$array) {
            my $name = get_hash_value($sub_hash, "name");
            my $project = get_hash_value($sub_hash, "project");
            my $source = get_hash_value($sub_hash, "source");
            my $key = join $;, $name, $project, $source;
            my $tools = get_hash_value($sub_hash, "tools", "ARRAY");
            my @tool_names;
            for my $item (@$tools) {
                my $name = get_hash_value($item, "name");
                push @tool_names, $name;
            }
            push @{ $save{$key} }, @tool_names;
        }
    }
    my @result;
    for my $key (keys %save) {
        my ($name, $project, $source) = split $;, $key;
        my $names = $save{$key};
        my @tools = map { +{ name => $_} } uniq @$names;
        push @result, {name => $name,
                       project => $project,
                       source => $source,
                       tools => \@tools };
    }
    return {tool_pointer => \@result};
}

sub get_hash_value($hash, $key, $ref="") {
    die "Not a hash ref\n" if ref $hash ne "HASH";
    die "Hash key '$key' does not exist\n" if !exists $hash->{$key};
    my $value = $hash->{$key};
    die "Unexpected hash value\n" if ref $value ne $ref;
    return $value;
}
```