# Unable to merge files in required format

Tags: perl, data-structures, merge

I am trying to merge two yml files with following `perl` code. But data is not writing in expected format.

Code:-

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dump;
use Data::Dumper;
use Storable qw(dclone);
use YAML qw(LoadFile Dump);
use File::Slurp qw(write_file);
use Hash::Merge qw(merge);
Hash::Merge::set_behavior('RETAINMENT_PRECEDENT');

die "Usage: $0 file1 file2\n" if @ARGV != 2;
my ($fname1, $fname2) = @ARGV;

my $yml1 = LoadFile($fname1);
my $yml2 = LoadFile($fname2);


my $res = merge($yml1, $yml2);
#print Dumper $res;
write_file("final.yml", Dump ($res));
```

Should we need to set any custom settings in perl `Hash::Merge` module?

Hash Merge change:-

```
Hash::Merge::specify_behavior(
    {   SCALAR => {
            SCALAR => sub { $_[1] },
            ARRAY  => sub { [ $_[0], @{ $_[1] } ] },
            HASH   => sub { $_[1] },
        },
        ARRAY => {
            SCALAR => sub { $_[1] },
            HASH   => sub { $_[1] },
            ARRAY => sub {    # Rule for 'local_pointer'
                if ( exists $_[0][0]->{data} && exists $_[1][0]->{data} && exists $_[0][0]->{name} && exists $_[1][0]->{name}){
                    #if ($_[0][0]->{name} eq $_[1][0]->{name}){
                     my @a1 = @{$_[0]};
                     my @a2 = @{$_[1]};
                     foreach my $i1 (0..$#a1) {
                         foreach my $i2 (0..$#a2) {
                             #if ($a1[$i1]->{name} eq $a2[$i2]->{name}){
                                 #print Dumper $a1[0]->{data};
                                 [   {   data => [
                                           $a1[$i1]->{data},
                                           $a2[$i2]->{data},
                                          ],
                                         name => $a2[$i2]->{name},
                                      }
                                 ]
                             #else{



                             #}
                             #}

                         }
                     }
                }
                else {
                      [ @{ $_[0] }, @{ $_[1] } ] }
            }
        },
        HASH => {
            SCALAR => sub { $_[1] },
            ARRAY  => sub { [ values %{ $_[0] }, @{ $_[1] } ] },
            HASH   => sub { Hash::Merge::_merge_hashes( $_[0], $_[1] ) },
        },
    },
    'M2',
);
```

Comment: Your YAML examples have indentation issues.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a simple merge on these yaml snippets without Hash::Merge, example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw[say];
use DDP;
use YAML qw[LoadFile];

my $yaml = {};
my @data;
foreach my $file ( './a.yml', 'b.yml' ) {
    my $y = LoadFile($file);
    push @{ $yaml->{src} }, @{ $y->{src} };
    foreach my $element ( @{ $y->{local_pointer} } ) {
        push @data, @{ $element->{data} };
    }
}
@{ $yaml->{local_pointer} } = @data;
say p $yaml;
```

output:

```
\ {
    local_pointer => [
        [0] {
            dir       => '/release/p_analysis' (U),
            exe       => 'bin/test.sh' (U),
            tool_name => 'power_hash' (U),
            type      => 'exe' (U)
        },
        [1] {
            dir       => '/complete/release/1.2/55603074' (U),
            name      => 'code_test.config' (U),
            tool_name => 'axi_ip' (U),
            type      => 'dir' (U)
        },
        [2] {
            dir       => '/hw/debug/test/log/' (U),
            exe       => 'log.pl' (U),
            tool_name => 'test1' (U),
            type      => 'exe' (U)
        },
        [3] {
            dir       => '/releaase_test/p_analysis' (U),
            exe       => 'bin/test1.sh' (U),
            name      => 'code_test.config' (U),
            tool_name => 'power1_hash' (U),
            type      => 'exe' (U)
        }
    ],
    src           => [
        [0] {
            dest => 'sw_config/' (U),
            ip   => 'TOT' (U),
            name => 'defs.yml' (U)
        },
        [1] {
            dest => 'models/' (U),
            ip   => 'TOT' (U),
            name => 'makebuild.vh' (U)
        },
        [2] {
            dest => 'sw_configs/' (U),
            ip   => 'TOT' (U),
            name => 'defs111.yml' (U)
        },
        [3] {
            dest => 'models/' (U),
            ip   => 'TOT' (U),
            name => 'testbuild.vh' (U)
        }
    ]
```

**UPDATE**

Here a `Hash::Merge` example with a specific rule for `local_pointer` as in the previous example:

```
my @yaml = map { LoadFile( sprintf './%s.yml', $_ ) } qw[a b];

my $merger = Hash::Merge->new();
$merger->add_behavior_spec(
    {   SCALAR => {
            SCALAR => sub { $_[1] },
            ARRAY  => sub { [ $_[0], @{ $_[1] } ] },
            HASH   => sub { $_[1] },
        },
        ARRAY => {
            SCALAR => sub { $_[1] },
            HASH   => sub { $_[1] },
            ARRAY => sub {    # Rule for 'local_pointer'
                if ( exists $_[0][0]->{data} && exists $_[1][0]->{data} ) {
                    # return joined arrays into 'data'                         
                    [   {   data => [
                                @{ $_[0][0]->{data} },    #
                                @{ $_[1][0]->{data} },    #
                            ],
                        }
                    ]
                }
                else { [ @{ $_[0] }, @{ $_[1] } ] }
            }
        },
        HASH => { 
            SCALAR => sub { $_[1] },
            ARRAY  => sub { [ values %{ $_[0] }, @{ $_[1] } ] },
            HASH   => sub { Hash::Merge::_merge_hashes( $_[0], $_[1] ) },
        },
    },
    'My Behavior',
);

my $yaml = $merger->merge(@yaml);
```

Comment: You can try to extend or generalize this approach depending on what this new key contains.

Comment: Ronaldo, I tried to make few changes for my requirement of having multiple elements in an array (updated question in a.yml,b.yml...etc). And I am trying to merge with few changes in `specify_behavior` , please see (`Hash Merge change` section in question.) Some reason ,i am getting `Useless use of anonymous array ([]) in void context at final_merge_testing.pl`  Not getting what is missing :(